# Load require.js module inside gulp task

Tags: requirejs, gulp

I have a require.js module that runs some benchmarks over my app modules. Usually this is opened manually via `benchmarksRunner.html`.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'someDependencies': ['someDependenciesPath'],
    },
});

require([
    'someModulePath'
], function (
    someModule
) {
    doSomeStuff
    return someResults (or dispatch event...)
});
```

From time to time I want to save these results inside a json file using gulp. I figured out how to save a json to the exact place where I want to store the results, but I'm stuck on how to retrieve the results of the benchmarks into gulp in the first place.

```
gulp.task('performance', function () {

    // Obviously this does not work...
    require('./src/libs/require/require.min.js');
    require('./tests/benchmarksMain.js');

    // I want to run the benchmarks as they are already 
    // configured in the benchmarksRunner.html using require.js

    // Somehow gulp should be able to start the require.js scripts
    // and wait for an arbitrary event, then run the code from bellow
    // (which works just fine)

    performanceResults = {'someResults': results};

    var fs = require('fs'),
    var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./tests/performance/performance.json'));
    json[dateFormat()] = performanceResults;
    json = JSON.stringify(json);

    return stringSrc('performance.json', json)
       .pipe(gulp.dest('tests/performance'))
}); 

function stringSrc (filename, string) {
    var src = require('stream').Readable({ objectMode: true });
    src._read = function () {
        this.push(new gutil.File({ cwd: "", base: "", path: filename, contents: new Buffer(string) }));
        this.push(null)
    };
    return src
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Reply for the answer that seems to have vanished: `node-amd-require` seems to be the solution, it has paths config object. However it raises an exception: `AssertionError: path must be a string`. It looks like it isn't able to load multiple modules at the same time using arrays. `require(['engine/utils/utils', 'benchmark'], function (utils, Benchmark) {});`

Comment: It really doesn't help me as long as it can't handle arrays of dependencies. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it necessary that the code loaded by RequireJS run in a *browser*?

Comment: It is, since I want to benchmark a lot of functions that relate to graphics (webgl). I want to track for changes in performance while the codebase evolves, while running the app with the full-blown UI.